# ADFv2 Bicep Managed Vnet

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, azure-bicep

I'd like to deploy an azure data factory along with a managed vnet containing an adf managed private endpoint to an azure sql db.

My bicep module is as follows:

```
param adfName string
param devopsId string
param vnetName string
param sqlId string

resource adf 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name:adfName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource integrationRuntime 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes@2018-06-01' = {
  name: '${adfName}/${adfName}-managedVnetIr' 
  properties: {
    type: 'Managed'
    typeProperties: {
      computeProperties: {
        location: 'AutoResolve'
        dataFlowProperties: {
          computeType: 'General'
          coreCount: 8
          timeToLive: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    adf
  ]
}

resource managedVnet 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks@2018-06-01' = {
  parent:adf
  name: 'managed-${vnetName}'
  properties: { 
  }
  dependsOn: [
    integrationRuntime
  ]
}

resource managedPrivateEndpoint 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks/managedPrivateEndpoints@2018-06-01' = {
  parent:managedVnet
  name: 'managed-${vnetName}-sql-pe'
  properties: {
    privateLinkResourceId:sqlId
    groupId: 'sql'
  }
}

var roleDefId = '673868aa-7521-48a0-acc6-0f60742d39f5'
resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(adf.id, devopsId, roleDefId)
  properties: {
    principalId: devopsId
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleDefId)
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}
```

When I run the deployment, all looks good except that *adfDeploy* never completes and eventually times out after approximately 80 minutes:

[image]

If I load the data factory studio I get the following error:

[image]

After waiting 80 minutes for the deployment timeout, the only information in the error is "Conflict". Any suggest where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Conflict errror : It means you are requesting an operation that isn't allowed in the resource's current state.

Please check if below points can be worked around.

1. According to microsoft doc reference  [azure data-factory
   -continuous-integration-delivery-Best practices for CI/CD.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#:%7E:text=Managed%20private%20endpoint,value%20during%20deployment)

   > You can successfully deploy a private endpoint as long as it has the
   > same properties as the one that already exists in the factory. If a
   > private endpoint already exists in a factory and you try to deploy an
   > ARM template that contains a private endpoint with the same name but
   > with modified properties, the deployment will fail.

   If you are trying to reference a existing vnet or newly created vnet
   , please check if you are missing dependency on parent  integration runtime.

   ```
   resource managedVnet 
   'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks@2018-06-01'
    = {
      parent:df
      name: vnetname
      properties: { 
      }
      dependsOn: [
        integrationRuntime
      ]
   ```

   Please check if the reference for above is related  > [Error in
   Bicep deployment of ManagedVNet IR for Azure Datafactory - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897155/error-in-bicep-deployment-of-managedvnet-ir-for-azure-datafactory)
2. To deploy a private endpoint on a given subnet, an explicit disable
   setting maybe required on that **subnet**.

   ```
   "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Disabled"
   ```

   Also check if that sql server has public access disabled.
   `publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'`

   [disable private endpoint network-policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/disable-private-endpoint-network-policy#disable-network-policy-2)

Also check References:

1. [Azure bicep issues](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/2579#issuecomment-834885518)
2. [managed virtual network private endpoint-limitations and known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint#limitations-and-known-issues)

Comment: Hi @kavyasaraboju-MT, I have updated the bicep module to reflect the change you suggested re adding a "dependsOn" for managed vnet to the integration runtime. I still see the same timeout after 80 minutes and the same error. Re point 2; I can confirm that this is disabled. I ensured the data factory was deleted before running the bicep. I also checked that the sql server had public access denied.